# How do improvised weapons work?

Tags: dnd-5e, improvised-weaponry

I know what an improvised weapon is — a shard of glass or a tree branch used as a weapon — but what damage do they do? Is it up to the DM to decide what dice is thrown to determine the damage or is there a way to always know which object does what?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation about the question's low quality and whose problem that is has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106982/discussion-on-question-by-morthos-timor-how-do-improvised-weapons-work). I would also like to remind users that after a certain amount (one or two comments-worth) of pushback its usually better to leave others alone. You've all given good and well-intentioned advice which OP can benefit from or not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### It depends on what improvised weapon you use

In the PHB under [Improvised Weapons](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#ImprovisedWeapons), it describes how improvised weapons are ruled:

> Sometimes characters don't have their weapons and have to attack with whatever is at hand. An improvised weapon includes any object you can wield in one or two hands, such as broken glass, a table leg, a frying pan, a wagon wheel, or a dead goblin.

If they are similar to any other known weapon, you can rule to use that weapon's damage dice and whether the player is proficient with it or not:

> Often, **an improvised weapon is similar to an actual weapon and can be treated as such**. For example, a table leg is akin to a club. At the DM's option, a character proficient with a weapon can use a similar object as if it were that weapon and use his or her proficiency bonus.

For any other object you use 1d4 as the damage diee:

> **An object that bears no resemblance to a weapon deals 1d4 damage** (the DM assigns a damage type appropriate to the object). If a character uses a ranged weapon to make a melee attack, or throws a melee weapon that does not have the thrown property, it also deals 1d4 damage. An improvised thrown weapon has a normal range of 20 feet and a long range of 60 feet.

As for the ability modifier, you usually use Strength, since improvised weapons don't have the Finesse property.

Answer (score 12):

This is outlined in the section [Improvised Weapons](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#ImprovisedWeapons) in the basic rules.

The relevant sections are

> Often, an improvised weapon is similar to an actual weapon and can be treated as such.

I.e. if your improvised weapon is actually sufficiently similar to an actual weapon you can just treat it the same as the actual weapon. The DM decides what constitutes sufficiently similar. If the DM decides that your broken glass bottle doesn't resemble any real weapon, then this section applies:

> An object that bears no resemblance to a weapon deals 1d4 damage

Also, while this isn't spelled out like this in the rules so this isn't RAW as such, but normally I'd want something to at least be plausibly better for hitting things with than just your bare hands to count it as a improvised weapon. So while a swim noodle is certainly an object you can hold in one or two hands so RAW technically qualifies as an improvised weapon, I'd not allow it in my games because that dealing more damage than hitting someone in the face with your fist doesn't make a lot of sense to me personally.